# how to print the number of lines in a file not including the header

Tags: shell

I have a file with a header "SELECT_GENES"

SELECT_GENES

Gene_1

Gene_2

Gene_3

When I do wc -l, I get 4. How can I get it to print the number excluding the header i.e. 3.

Comment: Just subtract one if there is only 1 line header

Comment: I am piping the wc -l command with another one which needs the number of lines excluding the header, so I need this number as the output of the wc command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tail` and `wc`:

```
tail -n +2 file | wc -l
3
```

`tail -n +2` gets lines starting from line #2.